# How to add Wordpress Page title as a variable in $args = array( loop to display posts related to tag

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom post type of countries. On the individual 'country' page I want to display a loop of another custom post type ('Itineraries') where the itineraries items are tagged with the same name as the country title. E.g. I want all Itinerary items tagged with the word 'Peru' to appear on the 'Peru' country page.

I have tried the following code which works if I hard code a country name e.g. 'Peru' . However I want to dynamically populate this with the country title of each page. I have tried replacing 'tag' => 'peru' with 'tag'=> $country_title but am not sure of the syntax. Thanks for any help.

```
<?php
$country_title = get_the_title();
//echo $country_title;
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'itinerary',  //Specifying post type
    'posts_per_page' => 10, //How many posts per page
   // 'cat' =>'cat2',         //Specifying post category to show posts
    'tag' =>'peru',
    'paged' => $paged       //For pagingation (if required)
    );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
xxxxxx
<?php 
endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thaks for the previous answer, however, my issue ws solved by the simple point of removing the single quotes from around the variable.

```
<?php
$country_title = get_the_title();
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'itinerary',  //Specifying post type
    'posts_per_page' => 10, //How many posts per page
   // 'cat' =>'cat2',         //Specifying post category to show posts
    'tag' =>$country_title,
    'paged' => $paged       //For pagingation (if required)
    );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you have tagged the country in that page or post, so you can use `wp_get_post_terms` to get the post terms where you pass the current page/post ID and taxonomy name. I am guessing you're using `post_tag` taxonomy as a tag then you can get the array of slugs by specifying `array( 'fields' => 'slugs' )` as 3rd param int hat function, then you can check if you have values in tags array or not then you can pass this array in `tag_slug__in` param in query args.

**Note: if you have other tags also available in that post then you'll have to think a way/logic to get only countries slugs, the below get will get all the tags assigned to current page/post and pass in query**

```php
$country_title = get_the_title();

$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// Get all the tags from the current post type.
$tags = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'post_tag', array( 'fields' => 'slugs' ) );

// If tags are available then only run the things.
if ( ! empty( $tags ) ) {
    $query_args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'itinerary',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'tag_slug__in'   => (array) $tags,
        'paged'          => $paged,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $query_args );

    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
            $loop->the_post();

            /**
             * Do your template things here.
             */
        endwhile;
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```